# Python / win32com / try and except / check if application is running

Tags: python, exception, win32com

I'm using python 3.6.2 on Windows 7.

I have a little function, that should check if MS Excel is already running or not. The function is behaving a little bit strange, here your help would be very appreciated.

The function should check, if Excel is running. If yes, print text and exit the application. If no, everything is fine, continue.

My Problem now is, when Excel **is** running the try-block is executed including the printing but not the sys.exit() **AND** the except-block is executed as well!?
If Excel is **NOT** running, then everything is fine, the try-block aborts and only the except-block is executed.

Why is it executing both print-statements, when Excel is running?

Please help!

Here's my code:

```
def check_if_Excel_runs():
    import win32com.client
    import sys
    try:
        win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
        # If there is NO error at this stage, Excel is already running
        print('Excel is running, please close first')
        sys.exit()
    except:
        print('Excel is NOT running, this is good!')
    return

check_if_Excel_runs()
```

My output (when Excel is running):

```
Excel is running, please close first
Excel is NOT running, this is good!
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I have understood, that I should not generally do "except" without specifiying the exception I want to handle. But how do I determin, of which type the exception is, that I want to catch. If I look at the error message, it is not clear to me.

```
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-70980aa1c5df> in <module>()
     11     return
     12 
---> 13 check_if_Excel_runs()

<ipython-input-39-70980aa1c5df> in check_if_Excel_runs()
      3     import sys
      4     try:
----> 5         win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
      6         # If there is NO error at this stage, Excel is already running
      7         print('Excel is running, please close first')

c:\users\chnn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py in GetActiveObject(Class, clsctx)
     77   """  
     78   resultCLSID = pywintypes.IID(Class)
---> 79   dispatch = pythoncom.GetActiveObject(resultCLSID)
     80   dispatch = dispatch.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
     81   return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, Class, resultCLSID = resultCLSID, clsctx = clsctx)

com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)
```

Thanks again for your help, folks!

Comment: The last line says `com_error: ...`, so your exception is of type `com_error`. You still need the package name. Typing `python com_error` into google yielded `pythoncom.com_error`, so that is your full exception type.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because sys.exit() throws an exception too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that sys.exit() is throwing an exception.

Sys.exit() exits by throwing a system exit exception. You can't put it in there and just use a general catch all statement.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the python docs on sys.exit() you can see what the problem is here:

> This is implemented by raising the SystemExit exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit attempt at an outer level.

So what happens is that the `sys.exit()` is being executed and tries to end the program by throwing the SystemExit exception. But since you wrote a generic except you catch the exception and then print the message.

You therefor provide an excellent example of why it is a bad idea to write generic exceptions, since you can end up catching exceptions you don't want to catch. you should look for the type of exception that

```
win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
```

throws and only catch that here.